# Why text box text not showing from starting position in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am really confused about this. Please consider below scenario.

**Scenario:**
I have a C# Winform app with few Textbox controls. Now when I input data in these text boxes, for example, "THIS IS MY SAMPLE TEXTBOX", which overlaps the Textbox's visible area and displaying as "AMPLE TEXTBOX". But I want the text to be displayed from the starting position like "THIS IS MY S" and then if needed, overlaps. How can I do this? I have tried below but no luck. Please help. Thanks.

```
(sender as TextBox).TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
```

**Edit**
I am also using `AutoCompleteMode.Suggest` so that when I press any key, corresponding list will be displayed similar to dropdownlist. But the first item of this list is selected by default, which I do not want. Can you please suggest in this also. Thanks.

**Final Solution**
I am using this to solve the issue

```
(sender as TextBox).TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
(sender as TextBox).Select(0, 0);
```

Thanks to @Har Har.

Comment: Is your textbox wide enough?

Comment: no..that is why I am trying to display the text from the beginning. Increasing the textbox width will not serve my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, To position the cursor at the beginning of the contents of a TextBox control, call the Select method and specify the selection start position of 0, and a selection length of 0.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Hello this is a sample application";
        textBox1.Select(0, 0);
    }
```

It will show the cursor position at 0 index, It's working.